# There is no polynomial $q$ such that $\int_0^1 p(x)q(x)\,dx=p(0)$ for each polynomial $p$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the inner product on $P(R)$ is defined by $\langle p,q\rangle = \int^1_0 p(x)q(x)dx$.

Let $\phi$ be the linear functional on $P(R)$ defined by $\phi (p) = p(0)$ for each polynomial $p \in P(R)$. Prove that there does not exist $q \in P(R)$ such that $\phi (p) = \langle p, q\rangle$ for every $p \in P(R)$.

This is what I have so far:

Let $e_1,...,e_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $P(R)$.

$\phi (p) = \phi(\langle p, e_1\rangle e_1 + \dots + \langle p, e_n\rangle e_n) = \langle p, e_1\rangle \phi(e_1) + \dots + \langle p, e_n\rangle \phi(e_n)$

Thus, $\phi(e_1)e_1 + \dots + \phi(e_n) e_n = p(0)e_1 + \dots p(0) e_n$

I'm not sure where to go from here, help? Thank you!

Comment: $q(x)$ does not appear in your $<p,q> = \int^0_1 p(x)(cos\pi x)dx$

Comment: Did you mean $\int_0^1p(x)q(x)\,dx$?

Comment: Also, what is $P(R)?$ And why do you have the integral endpoints out of order?

Comment: Ah sorry sorry it was a long question! P(R) is the set of all real-valued polynomials

Comment: Sigh. The set of all real polynomials is (countably) infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $p(x)=1$. We get $\int_0^1 q(x)dx=1$. Now take $p(x)=xq(x)$, we get $\int_0^1 x(q(x))^2dx=0$, hence $xq(x)^2=0$ on $[0,1]$ and $q(x)=0$. Hence $\int_0^1 q(x)dx=0=1$.

Comment: Look ma, no topology!  This is a really nice clean algebraic proof.  (Not that there's anything wrong with the other proofs - they use appropriate machinery!  I just like how this one could be explained to a gifted high-schooler, albeit with a little handwaving around showing that $\int_0^1p(x)dx = 0$ and $p(x)\geq 0$ on $[0,1]$ $\implies p(x)\equiv 0$ for polynomial $p()$.)

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki: Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

The vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients has infinite dimension, so there is no finite orthonormal basis as stated at the beginning of your work.  What follows the word "Thus" is very mysterious to me, and incorrect.

An alternative to the other suggestions is to consider $p_n(x)=(1-x)^n$ and use the bounded convergence theorem:  If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of integrable functions on $[0,1]$ converging pointwise to an integrable function $f$, and if there is a constant $M>0$ such that $|f_n(x)|<M$ for all $n$ and for all $x$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha}a_{n}x^{n}dx$ is a rational function in term of $\alpha$ assuming $\alpha\geq 0$.

Hence $\int\limits_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha}q(x)dx$ is still a rational function in term of $\alpha$.

Remember that rational function is ratio of 2 polynomial. Thus it have only a finite number of root. Hence only a finite number of $\alpha$ exist such that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha}q(x)dx=0$. But we need an infinite number of them, by plugging in $p(x)=x^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha=1,2,3,\ldots$

Comment: I like how this only relies on there being infinitely many such $\alpha$ (rather than all but finitely many for example).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Take the restriction $\phi_n$ of $\phi$ on the subspace $\Bbb R_n[x]$ of polynomials with degree less or equal $n$.

$\phi_n$ is   obviously continuous by *(in finite dimensional space all the norms are equivalent)*

$$|\phi_n(p)|\le \lVert p\rVert_\infty$$
so by the Riesz's theorem there's a *unique* $q_0$ such that
$$\phi_n(p)=\langle p,q_0\rangle$$

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Schwarz_inequality) we would have $$|p(0)| = |\langle p, q \rangle| \leq \lVert p\rVert\lVert q\rVert$$ for all polynomials $p$. Now consider this inequality for $p(x) = (1-x)^n$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: From this, it appears that the only "function" that works is the Dirac delta function $q(x) = \delta(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x^n$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ and use Weierstrass' theorem.